# What is a good, cheap, solution for managing patches over say 100 seperate domains

Tags: wsus, adobe, deployment

We are an IT support provider and I am looking at improving our existing systems. We have WSUS in place for Windows Updates but we are looking for the cheapest and quickest way possible of updating programs like Adobe Flash, Reader, and Java.

Any ideas would be welcome.

Answer (score 4):

If you have 100 separate customers, "cheapest" might not be appropriate. You've got to have the rights tools to do the job. When working for a managed-service company, we used Shavlik and mostly liked it.

Comment: +1 Sometimes you have to accept that what you want will cost a lot of either time or money, if not both.

Comment: I do agree. It is like being stuck between a rock and a hard place with cost and functionality. The cost is out of my hand though, I am just a lowly engineer!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Desktop Central?

http://www.manageengine.com/products/desktop-central/

Or perhaps for your specific need, MSP Center Lite?

http://www.manageengine.com/products/mspcenterlite/index.html

I do use their Desktop Central product at a few client sites and it seems to do a decent enough job for keeping the systems up to date. If they have some of the 3rd party products installed (Adobe, Java, etc.), it will also maintain those w/o any additional effort.

(They didn't have the MSP product at the time, else I might have went that route).